# Fedora 35 in VirtualBox: Why no space to install new software?

Tags: fedora

I've been using debian for many years but wanted to try Fedora.
So I installed the new Fedora 35 on a 50GB virtual disk using the installations automatic partitioning feature. When everything was installed and ready, the first thing I did was to try install some large software. It didnt work.

```
Unable to install "XXX"
Error running transaction: installing package
"XXX" needs 458MB more space on the / filesystem
```

Why can't the software be installed?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running the installed system? The screenshot suggest you are still in the LiveCD environment.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny You are right! When I removed the installation media from virtualbox, the real Fedora starts. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the image, you are still in the LiveCD environment (you can see the `live-base` and `live-rw` block devices, which is the LiveCD system running from memory). You need to reboot the system after the installation finishes and make sure the Fedora CD is ejected/removed from the VM. If you still end up on the LiveCD boot screen (some virtualization tools require shutting down the system to change the boot order and/or remove CDs), you can boot the installed system by selecting *Troubleshooting Fedora Workstation Live -> Boot from local drive*.